# Why am I getting a "401 - Unauthorized" error when sending a file byte stream to a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, iis-7

I have a WCF service with a basicHttp binding hosted on II7 being called from a Silverlight client.  I can call all of the services on the endpoint without issue 
except for one.

I'm trying to upload a file so the service receives a byte array.  If I upload files over 3MB in size, I get the error below.

When I try calling this service:

```
[OperationContract]
public AuditResponse UploadVendorAuditFile( int vendorID, 
                                            int sourceSystemID, 
                                            string fileName,
                                            byte[] fileBytes )
{
    // stuff
}
```

I get the following error:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You
>   do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

Here are my configurations.

**Endpoint Binding**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding 
    name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration" 
    maxBufferSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    >
    <readerQuotas 
    maxDepth="2147483647" 
    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
    maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" 
    />
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

**Service Configuration**

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Client**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding 
              name="BasicHttpBinding_WMService" 
              maxBufferSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
              >
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Are the files for which it fails are bigger in size say greater than 1MB or so? Also try enabling tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to know the actual cause of the error. If the files are of larger size then it might be cause of the reader quota settings which need to be set for larger values on both server and client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the files for which it fails are bigger in size say greater than 1MB or so? Try enabling [**tracing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)  to know the actual cause of the error.

If the files are of larger size then it might be cause of the reader quota settings which need to be set for larger values on **both server and client side**

Also consider adding the maxItemsInObjectGraph in your serviceBehaviour as shown

```
 <serviceBehaviors>        
    <behavior>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

**NOTE: Make sure to have the same readerQuotas settings on both client and server side**

Also try to set the below setting in your web.config

```
<system.web>  
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="32768"/>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: I posted both my service config and my client config.  They seem to be configured correctly.  I've now noticed it is when a file is over 3MB.

Comment: see an update to set the httpRuntime maxRequestLength property

Comment: Wouldn't have figured that out myself. WCF is so difficult to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the max message size in your bindings on the WCF service..

For Example:

```
<binding name="xxx" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="50000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
</binding>
```